# Kubernetes how to access application in one namespace from another

Tags: mongodb, go, kubernetes

I have the following components up and running in a kubernetes cluster

- A GoLang Application writing data to a mongodb statefulset replicaset in namespace `app1`
- A mongodb replicaset (1 replica) running as a statefulset in the namespace `ng-mongo`

What I need to do is, I need to access the mongodb database by the `golang` application for write/read opeations, so what I did was;

1. Create a headless service for the `mongodb` in the `ng-mongo` namespace as below:

```
# Source: mongo/templates/svc.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongo
  namespace: ng-mongo
  labels:
    app: mongo
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 27017
    targetPort: 27017
    name: mongo
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    role: mongo
```

2. And then I deployed the `mongodb` statefulset and initialized the replicaset as below:

```
kubectl exec -it mongo-0 -n ng-mongo mongosh
rs.initiate({_id: "rs0",members: [{_id: 0, host: "mongo-0"}]})


// gives output 
{ ok: 1 }
```

3. Then I created an `ExternalName` service in the `app1` namespace linking the above mongo service in step 1, look below:

```
# Source: app/templates/svc.yaml
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: app1
  namespace: app1
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: mongo.ng-mongo.svc.cluster.local
  ports:
  - port: 27017
```

4. And at last, I instrumented my `golang` application as follows;

```
// Connection URI 
const mongo_uri = "mongodb://app1" <-- Here I used the app1, as the ExternalName service's name is `app1`

<RETRACTED-CODE>
```

And then I ran the application, and checked the logs. Here is what I found:

> 2022/11/22 12:49:47 server selection error: server selection timeout, current topology: { Type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary, Servers: [{ Addr: mongo-0:27017, Type: Unknown, Last error: connection() error occurred during connection handshake: dial tcp: lookup mongo-0 on 10.96.0.10:53: no such host }, ] }

**Update: I haven't set any usernames or passwords for the mongodb**

Can someone help me why this is happening?

Comment: Any reason not to point your mongo_uri to `mongo.ng-mongo.svc.cluster.local` directly? Why introduce that ExternalName service? Meanwhile: you probably need to use FQDNs in rs.initiateMembers: mongo-0 would not resolve from your application namespace point of view.

Comment: @SYN thank you for your suggestion, finally fixed it by adding the `FQDNs` of the `mongo-0` pod to the `rs.initiate({_id: "rs0",members: [{_id: 0, host: "mongo-0.mongo.ng-mongo.svc.cluster.local:27017"}]})`

Answer (score 1):

After some digging, I was able to find the issue.

When specifying the `host` entry for the `rs.initiate({})`, I should provide the `FQDN` of the relevant `mongodb` instance (in my case it is the `mongo-0` pod). Therefore, my initialisation command should look like this;

```
rs.initiate({_id: "rs0",members: [{_id: 0, host: "mongo-0.mongo.ng-mongo.svc.cluster.local:27017"}]})
```

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of what you are trying to do,

Your Pod(golang application) and `app1` Service are already in the same namespace.

However, looking at the log,

> 2022/11/22 12:49:47 server selection error: server selection timeout, current topology: { Type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary, Servers: [{ Addr: mongo-0:27017, Type: Unknown, Last error: connection() error occurred during connection handshake: dial tcp: lookup mongo-0 on 10.96.0.10:53: no such host }, ] }

The log means that the domain named 'mongo-0' could not be found in DNS. (Note that 10.96.0.10 IP is probably kube-dns)

Your application tries to connect to the domain `mongo-0`, but the domain `mongo-0` does not exist in DNS (It means there is no service named `mongo-0` on `app1` namespace).

What is the 'mongo-0' that your Application trying to access?
(Obviously the log shows an attempt to access the domain `mongo-0` and your golang applications `mongo_uri` indicates `mongodb://app1`)

Finding out why your application are trying to connect to the `mongo-0` domain will help solve the problem.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Hi Devin, sorry it was a mistake, the `app1` ExternalName Service is already in the `app1` namespace, I updated my question.

Comment: oh got it. Just to clarify it more, what is the `mongo-0` in the log? It seems that the application access to `mongo-0` domain but this domain is not shown your codes.

Comment: I updated my answer again as per your question update :)

Comment: Hi, thank you, it was the problem when initializing. I have given a hostname which is not in the /etc/hosts entry of the `mongo-0` pod